# Pulseaudio randomly mute itself without a reason

Tags: pulseaudio, 14.04, disconnect

I recently installed fresh Ubuntu 14.04. I've got external audio card Audiotrak Maya U5. It always worked fine until new Ubuntu. Music randomly get muted and there's no visible changes in sound settings or anything.
I mean, it even doesn't look like it's muted, the sound just doesn't work. What I have to do then is to close the music player, wait a minute and run it again to get my sound back.
What could be the problem? Thx a lot!

PS sry for my poor english.

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem. Pulseaudio tries to be smart and mute music when you get a phone call - but you know what happens when programs try to be smart.

1. Edit this file as root: /etc/pulse/default.pa
2. Find these two lines:
   `###Cork music/video streams when a phone stream is active
   load-module module-role-cork`
3. Comment out the `load-module`:
   `#load-module module-role-cork`
4. Stop pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k`, then start it again.

You may have to restart your audio applications, but it should stop muting your music. It worked for me.

p.s. I know this question is old, but it pops up at the top of search results, so I'm answering it here.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 the `load-module` is commented out by default. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/527495/audio-jumps-to-full-volume-or-mutes-randomly

Comment: Had that problem in Ubuntu Mate 20.04. `load-module` was not commented out. Glad I found the reason.