# Audio jumps to full volume or mutes randomly

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, mute

I'm on 14.04 and I get volume spikes randomly. I first noticed it only when using Spotify so I thought it was a software issue with Spotify, now I've started it noticing sometimes when playing through flash as well so I'm thinking it has more likely to do with pulseaudio. Please help me troubleshoot this. What commands can I run to get you the information you need?

**Update:**
I've now started getting the audio muted randomly and I haven't noticed the spikes in a while. There's nothing that I've done, no settings I've changed. But this is even more annoying since I used to be able to max out the volume in Ubuntu and control it with my external speakers instead, but when it get's muted there's nothing I can do to workaround it. Thoughts?

Comment: I have the same issue on my Ubuntu 14.04. By the way this my Ubuntu was originally Xubuntu and I suspect this issue is rather from Xubuntu, because I never experienced this with stock Ubuntu, whereas experienced several times in Xubunt 12 and Xubuntu 14

Comment: Vak, I'm beginning to suspect it has something to do with pulseaudio and JACK not playing nice when both are installed. Do you also have JACK on your system?

Comment: interesting. Do you mean libjack-jackd2-0:amd64 ? this is the only entry for "dpkg -l|grep jack" by me.

Comment: And if i see it right, libjack-jackd2-0:amd64 is in the stock ubuntu 14.04 distro...

Comment: No, I mean the full on server, think the package is called jackd or jackd-server. Then I guess it might not be related to it :/

Answer (score 3):

I had experienced exactly the same issue on my Debian Stretch some hours ago. If I read [this report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/874535) correctly then it seem that there are bugs with some motherboards and pulseaudio.

Follow [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/874535/comments/33) to verify in pulseaudio log that your problem is related with flaky jack sensing. If so then you may find other comments on that bug report helpful:

> Change `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf`
>   from:

```
[Jack Front Headphone]
required-any = any

[Jack Headphone]
required-any = any
```

> to :

```
# [Jack Front Headphone]
# required-any = any

# [Jack Headphone]
# required-any = any
```

> [You'll have to] restart pulseaudio (or the computer) for changes to take effect.

and:

> There might actually a better solution in newer kernels: if you install the daily DKMS package you will get this too.
>   Then edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel jackpoll_ms=250
```

> [And] then reboot and test. In case the sound card is not the first hda intel sound card, you might need to add more, like this:

```
options snd-hda-intel jackpoll_ms=0,250
```

> or:

```
options snd-hda-intel jackpoll_ms=0,0,250
```

> ... depending on which card you want to change.

This bug was reported in 2011 but comments from 2015-12 as well as my own issue confirm that it's still present.

Comment: The issue still there. Kubuntu 18.04 uname -r 5.1.6-050106-generic Only physically disconnected front panel audio connector on the motherboard helped to almost solve the issue. Now sound interrupts much more rarely i.e. once in 30 min. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/874535/comments/82